# How to escape a special character in Hive shell/JDBC statement?

Tags: sql, character, hive, dollar-sign

I'm trying to create an external table from a JSON file, which looks like this:

```
{"id": "0010001", "my$entities": [{"a": "foo", "b": "bar"}]}
```

this is a file on HDFS and I don't have control on it.

I was using [rcongiu's JSON serde](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) and wrote my statement like this:

```
create external table json3(  id STRING,
my$entities STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/my/path/to/dir/';
```

But then the hive shell kept complaining:

> cannot recognize the input near 'ities' 'STRING' ')' in column type

I assume that it's the dollar sign "$" causing the problem. For right now I've tried using a backtick(`) and backward, forward slash to escape it but with no luck. I would like to know if there's a way to get around this without changing the original data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a $ sign in a Hive column name, but you can map `my$entities` to any other valid name.
E.g:

```
create external table json3(  id STRING,
myentities STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "mapping.myentities" = "my$entities" )  
LOCATION '/my/path/to/dir/';
```

Here the Hive column name `myentity` is mapped to the JSON attribute `my$entity`.
Reference: [Hive-JSON-Serde readme](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

Comment: oops can't believe i missed the mapping feature in the readme. However there's a typo in your answer, it should be: `create external table json3(  id STRING,
myentities STRING ) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "mapping.myentities" = "my$entities" )  
LOCATION '/my/path/to/dir/'; ` right? I fixed my problem thanks to the mapping feature.